# Java, make sure objects are being deleted when removed from arrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, garbage

Lets say that I'm deleting a "dead" object called "Enemy".

Using something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    {
    Enemy en = (Enemy) enemies.get(i);
    if(en.getVisible() == true)
        en.update();
    else
        enemies.remove(i);
    }
```

Does the object get deleted after being removed from ArrayList? Or "should" it? I've been mainly doing C++ code before and the garbage collection confuses me.

Any way I can see if the objects are being deleted or not by the garbage collector?

Thanks

Comment: In java, you don't have to worry about these cases. Garbage collector takes care of this.

Comment: No, they won't be deleted, you'll get `ConcurrentModificationException` :)

Comment: Yes.I am about say that . Thanks @denis.solonenko...Mason did you even run this code?

Comment: after remove try to get that object and you'll know if its deleted

Comment: @Mason.. If you want to remove an item from a Collection implemenation , suggested approach is to take `Iterator` and remove items from Iterator. otherwise you will get `ConcurrentModificationException `

Comment: @denis.solonenko - I think only when you use `Iterator`, it'll throw that exception. But if you manually loop through like this, it won't.

Comment: @R.J... I have tried this approach that you said with no `Iterator`, I still got that error when I used `for`

Comment: @SrinivasR - I did that too. And I didn't get the error. Fascinating, isn't it.

Comment: you'd get the exception if you were using an iterator but used `list.remove()` instead of `iterator.remove()`

Comment: I don't get any error or exceptions when I use it like this.

Comment: The for-each loop will throw Exceptions; the plain for loop will not.  It can't because java doesn't "know" what you're doing here; as far as it's concerned you're iterating over `i`.

Answer (score 1):

I really like seeing the opposite of the whole garbage collecting fiasco with C/C++ and Java. Java has it's own garbage collector, you do not need to worry about memory management - .remove() will suffice.

Comment: Not really true, you can still leak memory in Java if you keep a reference to enemy object in some other collection for example and forget to clear it

Comment: @denis.solonenko True, but if you are keeping a reference to it without any intention to use it then that's just bad practice. You can memory leak in Java but it's rare, certainly not as easy to do as in C.

Comment: On one hand it's cool, but I wish there were an easier method to call the garbage collector to cull the object when I don't need it any more. I wonder why they didn't add a keyword similar to delete, but "safer".

Answer (score 1):

If you remove an object from ArrayList, and that object doesn't have any other reference, then it would be 'eligible' for the garbage collector. After that, you need not worry about removing it from the heap: JVM would do that through automatic garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you entered the object. If you saved it elsewhere it should be still in existence, however if you directly added it to the arrayList it probably is garbage.

P.S. your code needs a correction

```
enemies.remove(i);
enemies.remove(i--);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking my comment about `ConcurrentModificationException` back. You won't get it, but your loop is still not correct. Take a look:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D"));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String s = list.get(i);
    if ("B".equals(s) || "C".equals(s)) list.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[A, C, D]
```

`C` is not removed due to `i` always increasing and skipping elements.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you won't need to worry about explicit memory management in Java - as long as there are no other objects referring to them after being removed from the list, the garbage collector will (eventually) remove them.

If the objects in the `enemies` list are holding onto some system resource or something else that needs to be explicitly disposed of (say a file handle or something), you'll want to clean this up before losing the reference:

```
Enemy enemy = enemies.remove();
enemy.dispose(); // this is your method to clean up the internals - name it what you want
// continue your loop here
```

On a note related to your sample code, you'll want to use an `Iterator` rather than just a for loop iterating over the indexes so you can `remove` properly without running into issues around the current index and list size. You may also want to consider a different `List` implementation (such as `LinkedList`, as insert/remove from the middle of an `ArrayList` can get expensive if it's big.

For your other question:

> Any way I can see if the objects are being deleted or not by the garbage collector?

You could [override the `finalize` method](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2012/03/finalize-method-in-java-tutorial.html) of your class - [be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635749/what-is-the-use-of-overriding-the-finalize-method-of-object-class) when you do this though.  Also note that there are [no guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636351/836214) when your objects will be garbage collected - different JVMs often manage memory slightly differently, and often only do garbage collection when it needs more memory.